# I have dynamic title tag in my wordpress but seo analyst show "No title Tag found error"?

Tags: search, title, wp-title

```
<title> 

    <?php if ( is_single() ) {
        single_post_title('', true); 
    } else {
        bloginfo('name'); echo " - "; bloginfo('description');
    }
    ?>


    </title>
```

This is my title tag code used for my wordpress blog. But Seo analyst shows `No title tag` found error

Comment: Where is this code? And this isn't going to be dynamic for category or date archives. Why not just use `wp_title()`, or better yet `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' )`?

Comment: Can you pls explain me detaily

Answer (score 0):

single_post_title only works on single posts, so you are okay using this.  First thing you could try is changing "true" to "false" to make the title be returned in the title tag you've created. If that doesn't fix it then try adding an h1 as below (which i don't think you'll need).

SEO is also looking for  an H1 (title) tag i believe as well.  If you enclose your single_post_title in an h1 tag it will eliminate your seo problem together with changing return output to false:

```
<h1><title> 

<?php if ( is_single() ) {
    single_post_title('', false); 
} else {
    bloginfo('name'); echo " - "; bloginfo('description');
}
?>

</title></h1>
```

The other option is to just use this:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to be adding your own title tag in a WordPress theme in 2018 (or [2014](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.1)). Instead, in your theme's functions file you should leave the `<title>` tag out of your header and [register your theme's support for title tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#title-tag) so that WordPress can add it for you:

```
function wpse_295641_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_295641_setup_theme' );
```

Now WordPress will add the tag to your head for you and it will be completely dynamic and support all the standard WordPress pages/archives/URLs.

If you want to customise it further, you can use the [`document_title_parts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) hook, or if you want to change the separator, you can use [`document_title_separator`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_separator/) hook.